# Is there an online source for pre-1942 UK general election polls from the British Institute of Public Opinion?

Tags: united-kingdom, public-opinion, reference-request, data-sources

I know that there are records of UK general election polls from before 1942, since I have read them in back issues of *Cavalcade* in the British Library (because I'm fun). I'm looking for an online record because

1. I didn't have time to write them all down
2. I don't really want to make a special trip to London to do that.

The polls were conducted by the British Institute of Public Opinion from 1937 on, a subsidiary of the Gallup organisation.

The UK Data Archive thinks it has them but the responses to these questions are blank. I'm asking this here because the history stack doesn't like reference requests for some reason.